# Cannot commit - messed up my sourceCode control, how to fix it?

Tags: ios, xcode, version-control, commit, fatal-error

Hello fellow programmers,

I accidentally added my whole project to my project, not once, but twice, as I was looking for another functionality. Since the folders didn't show up in Xcode itself, I went to Finder and deleted them manually from the filesystem again (so far so good, since I got all warning 4x).

But now, when I want to commit changes to the sourceCode control, I get this error:

```
fatal: Could not switch to '/Users/myID/Developer/iOS/ProjectName/ProjectName/ProjectName': No such file or directory
```

I have pretty much no clue what to do, has anyone ever had such a problem? Cleaning the project does not help, that's all I could think off, as I'm not that experienced!

Help I HIGHLY appreciated!

PS: I'm running Xcode 4.3.2 on OSX 10.7.4

Comment: Going to need more info: what source control are you using (Git/SVN/other)? What does the relevant `status` command say (e.g. `git status`)? How are you trying to commit?

Comment: just rebuild it from scratch - make a new project and drag in your classes. if you have a storyboard you can switch it out for the one in the new project

Comment: @Tim: I'm using apple's build in Git

Answer (score 1, accepted):

For something as serious as this I would create a new git repo, starting from the commit revision **before** the screw-up.

Assume your code is in `~/Source/MyProject`.

- First you are going to need the *commit revision* before the screw-up.  You can get his from the command line using `git log` or better still you can use the excellent (and free) [SourceTree](http://www.sourcetreeapp.com) Mac App.  Lets assume it's 62a6614fb55d692cd5a6e251cc05dea45d9668fe.
- Next start a new repo: `$ mkdir ~/Source/MyProjectNew; cd ~/Source/MyProject/New; git init`.
- Add the old project as the 'remote origin' of the new project: `$ git remote add origin ~/Source/MyProject`.
- Fetch the pre-screwed code: `$ git fetch origin 62a6614fb55d692cd5a6e251cc05dea45d9668fe`.
- Reset the master branch to the pre-screwed commit: `$ git reset --hard FETCH_HEAD`.
- Remove the origin: `$ git remote rm origin`.

You now have a new repo without the screwed-up code.  You need to rename the old and new repo and carry on with your life.